# Simplistic jQuery Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, widget

I am simply needing a jQuery-based calendar component that:

1. uses very few lines of jQuery code
2. uses very view lines of CSS
3. doesn't require that I install an entire jQuery UI library and stuff like that
4. simply lets you pick the date on any given year or month
5. always displays a single month, inline -- not fullscreen/huge, not a popdown
6. no week number display
7. no time display
8. no multiple calendars -- just one month
9. sends an event trigger when one clicks a particular date, and highlights that date
10. defaults to an assignable date
11. lets one start the week either on monday or sunday

So far, I haven't seen anything like that out there. Anyone seen one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[John Leighton's Date Input](http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input)**

The most light-weight, simple date picker I've found.  Doesn't sacrifice on looks to accomplish it like some other light-weight date pickers, which is why it gets my pick.

[Download here.](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1265/release)